# How to use a string as an object index that I know it is a key of that type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type like

```js
type Activity = {
  status: string,
  id: number,
  ...
  lotOfOhterProps
}
```

And I have a function that update tha activity based on inputs

```js
function update(actitvity: Activity, input: {field: string, content:string}){
  // this got an error because field can not be used as index
  activity[input.field]=input.content
}
```

But I am 100% sure that this field is one of the possible props of the type.

So, how to solve this?

I have a function

Comment: _Tell the compiler_ you're sure of that, use e.g. `keyof Activity` instead of just `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to type check, the compiler needs to know not only that `input.field` is one of the keys of `Activity` (i.e., `keyof Activity` using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)), it also needs to know that `input.content` is of the correct property *value* type corresponding to the key.  That means you should make `update()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `input.field`, and tell the compiler that `input.content` will be of type `Activity[K]`, the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) meaning "the property type of `Activity` at the index of type `K`":

```
function update<K extends keyof Activity>(
  activity: Activity,
  input: { field: K, content: Activity[K] }
) {
  activity[input.field] = input.content;
}
```

Now that compiles with no error, and should also provide some type safety when you call it:

```
declare const act: Activity;
update(act, { field: "id", content: 123 }); // okay
update(act, { field: "status", content: 123 }); // error! number is not string
update(act, { field: "status", content: "abc" }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aKBeKBvAUFKAZ2AENgBXQgLiOACdEA7AcwBp8pEATGx8gWwBGEOuwIB6cQQA2Ae2AB5AGYKAFsBEAFOrLCFcAX1y5JsRlygBJKKpLJoJKEvKMEiWYyjBbwKOTBcZNDejiRuqOiCJIQQFh6cjGDkwPq4zq5I8f6BGgA8ANJQEAAeGuaEUADWECCySrDhaCAAfAAUHGFIESA08F1NYglJwDTYTogQ0jxQ+axQcB5lIw39oADa+QC6UEYAlDgdjetMwwB0ShNT21gnyacLjEuGxlwQcNIkdNAPxFCdvUcQABuXDZIKtTpzMYXSbTABE3DhcweSxoAEYAEwAZh2uyBUFMskqJBAoIC4MhOHGsJocOIZEoSPmiwgj3R2Nx+NMIh0dAAhFA+EIRJwKox5LQGCwyTkIBCEFDqVNafSKIQmSjWcs4SRBHA4ZyCVIiSTcEA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation to access the property using the input.field as a string. Like this:

```
function update(activity: Activity, input: {field: string, content: string}) {
  activity[input.field as keyof Activity] = input.content;
}
```

The as keyof Activity syntax is called a type assertion and it tells TypeScript that input.field can be used as an index/key to access the Activity object properties.